# Recovering Unallocated space on dual boot machine (Ubuntu, Win 10)

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I am trying to recover some unallocated space on a Windows 10/ Ubuntu dual boot machine.  I have a lot of unallocated space (633.42Gb).  I tried to recover this using GParted but it will not let me use this space (as it states not more than 4 allowed?). Can you please let me know how I can recover this lost unallocated space to Ubuntu and Windows.

[image: GParted screenshot]

Comment: Try creating a logical partition?

Answer (score 1):

**Create a logical partition**

Good to know:

When you install an OS in MBR/BIOS mode you can't have more than four primary partitions. This is the same for Windows and Ubuntu. Also, when you create a logical partition, it is treated like a container for more partitions but the actual logical partition (the container) will be treated as a primary partition. The only way to overcome this is installing your OS in UEFI/GPT mode. Then you can have way more than four partitions.

You can read this up [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/193669/whats-the-difference-between-gpt-and-mbr-when-partitioning-a-drive/)

**What to do**

You should delete the swap partition first, so it is unallocated space. The next step is to create a logical partition using all of the space you have. Finally create your "inner" partitions - one swap and one whatever you want it to be, as long it is not a partition used for system stuff (/boot for example).

You should be done now.